# Place Table and 2 Figures on one page

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I am trying to place a tall table on the left side of the page and 2 small figures next to the table (see image). I have gotten the table a figure to work with wrapping but I haven't been able to get all three places.

Thank you in advance for the help.[image: Table and Figure Placement created in MS Word]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE? Does table height had to be bigger than sum pf images heights?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you post your code, what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I may serve as starting point. table and images are inserted in `tabularx` where in the first column is `\multirow` cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setcellgapes{9pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} m{16em} X @{}}
\multirow{9}{*}{
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{  |c|c|c| }
    \hline
example &           &           \\  \hline
        & example   &           \\  \hline
        &           & example   \\  \hline
        & example   &           \\  \hline
example &           &           \\  \hline
        & example   &           \\  \hline
        &           & example   \\  \hline
        & example   &           \\  \hline
example &           &           \\  \hline
\end{tabular}}  &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=T]{example-image-duck} \\
                &   \\
                &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]